# merging two array lists in java

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have two arraylists

arraylist dName has values:

```
mark, 22 

peter, 34

ken, 55
```

arraylist dest has values:

```
mark, London 

peter, Bristol

mark, Cambridge
```

I want to join merge them so that their output gives:

- mark

  London

  Cambridge
- peter

  Bristol
- Ken

> this is the code i have for now, i'm not really usre how to split on the comma and search the other array

```
public class Sample {

BufferedReader br;
BufferedReader br2;

public Sample() {


    ArrayList<String> dName = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> dest = new ArrayList<String>();

    String line = null;
    String lines = null;

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("taxi_details.txt"));
        br2  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("2017_journeys.txt"));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null &&
        (lines = br2.readLine()) != null){

            String name [] = line.split(";");
            String destination [] = lines.split(",");

            // add values to ArrayList
            dName.add(line);
            dest.add(lines);


            // iterate through destination
            for (String str : destination) {
            }
        }  
  } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {  
   }    
}
```

Comment: you called it an "arraylist," so I am guessing this is Java, but you really should tag what language you are working with. As well, I would suggest taking a look at how to format your question using markdown. Stackoverflow gives you some hints and a preview. It is difficult to tell exactly what you are asking. Can you post your code? Finally, have you googled it?

Comment: thanks. yes i have tried google, but i'm not getting what i want. manybe im usng the wrong terms?

Comment: Would the output be `["mark, London, Cambridge", "peter, Bristol", "Ken"]`. Or, I guess more accurately, what types are you dealing with? Strings? As well, I would suggest looking at the data structure "map". It sounds like it could help you out here

Comment: It seems like you have a list (A) and a HashMap (B). How can B be a list if is composed like a key - value structure? Could you post what you have done so far?

Comment: Please learn about `Map` in Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I'm not sure whether this is the proper way, but at least it is working.

**taxi_details.txt**

```
mark, 22
peter, 34
ken, 55
```

**2017_journeys.txt**

```
mark, London
peter, Bristol
mark, Cambridge
```

**FileReader**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class FileReader {
    public List<String> read(String fileName) throws IOException{
        return Files.lines(new File(fileName).toPath()).collect(Collectors.toList());       
    }
}
```

This class lets you avoid all the messy `try-catch` blocks.

**Line**

```
public class Line{
    public static final String DELIMITER = ",";
    public static final int INDEX_NAME = 0;
    public static final int INDEX_VALUE = 1;

    private String line;
    private String[] values;

    public Line(String line) {
        this.line = line;
        this.values = line.split(DELIMITER);
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.values[INDEX_NAME];
    }

    public String getValue(){
        return this.values[INDEX_VALUE];
    }

    public void emptyValue(){
        this.values[INDEX_VALUE] = "";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.line;
    }
}
```

This class has the mere prupose of preparing the data as needed for merging.

**Main**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader();

        // Read lines
        List<String> dName = fileReader.read("taxi_details.txt");
        List<String> dest = fileReader.read("2017_journeys.txt");

        // Convert into proper format
        List<Line> dNameLines = dName.stream().map(Line::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Line> destLines = dest.stream().map(Line::new).collect(Collectors.toList());

        // Remove ID
        dNameLines.forEach(Line::emptyValue);

        // Merge lists
        Map<String, String> joined = join(dNameLines, destLines);

        // Print
        for (Entry<String, String> line: joined.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(line.getKey() + " --> " + line.getValue());
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, String> join(List<Line> a, List<Line> b){
        Map<String, String> joined = new HashMap<>();

        // Put first list into map, as there is no danger of overwriting existing values
        a.forEach(line -> {
            joined.put(line.getName(), line.getValue());
        });

        // Put second list into map, but check for existing keys
        b.forEach(line -> {
            String key = line.getName();

            if(joined.containsKey(key)){    // Actual merge
                String existingValue = joined.get(key);
                String newValue = line.getValue();

                if(!existingValue.isEmpty()){
                    newValue = existingValue + Line.DELIMITER + newValue;
                }

                joined.put(key, newValue);
            }else{  // Add entry normally
                joined.put(line.getName(), line.getValue());
            }
        });

        return joined;
    }
}
```

You might want to move the `join` method into its own class.

**Output**

```
peter -->  Bristol
ken --> 
mark -->  London, Cambridge
```

Answer (score -1):

You should iterate on array B.

For each string, split on the comma and search in A for a string that *starts with* the first part of the split.

Then append the second part of the split to the entry found in A.

Comment: But what about elements of A that don't appear in B (in the example, `ken`)

Comment: It will simply stay as it was, as the desired output in the above question. With this answer array A is actually modified to give the desired output.